# Функции вызываются по несколько раз | Kotlin

Tags: функции, kotlin, android-fragment, activity, navigationcontroller

У меня есть 3 метода:

```
initWeeklyView()
initRankingView()
initRankingMonthView()
```

Которые я вызываю в OnCreateView.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browse_fragment, container, false)

    WeeklyFeaturedGridView = root?.findViewById(R.id.weeklyFeaturedView)
    RankingFeaturedRecyclerView = root?.findViewById(R.id.rankingFeaturedView)
    RankingFeaturedMonthRecyclerView = root?.findViewById(R.id.rankingFeaturedMonthView)

    initWeeklyView()
    initRankingView()
    initRankingMonthView()

    return root
}
```

Странность в том, что, когда я замерял время инициализации, методы вызываются по несколько раз.
Вот лог:

```
2020-10-17 18:42:58.688 I/Chronometer: initWeeklyView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:42:59.728 I/Chronometer: initWeeklyView завершен!
2020-10-17 18:42:59.728 I/Chronometer: initRankingView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:43:00.934 I/Chronometer: initRankingView завершен!
2020-10-17 18:43:00.934 I/Chronometer: initRankingMonthView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:43:02.007 I/Chronometer: initRankingMonthView завершен!
2020-10-17 18:43:02.041 I/Chronometer: initWeeklyView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:43:03.229 I/Chronometer: initWeeklyView завершен!
2020-10-17 18:43:03.229 I/Chronometer: initRankingView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:43:04.440 I/Chronometer: initRankingView завершен!
2020-10-17 18:43:04.440 I/Chronometer: initRankingMonthView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:43:05.346 I/Chronometer: initRankingMonthView завершен!
2020-10-17 18:43:06.507 I/Chronometer: initWeeklyView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:43:07.718 I/Chronometer: initWeeklyView завершен!
2020-10-17 18:43:07.718 I/Chronometer: initRankingView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:43:09.171 I/Chronometer: initRankingView завершен!
2020-10-17 18:43:09.171 I/Chronometer: initRankingMonthView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:43:10.079 I/Chronometer: initRankingMonthView завершен!
2020-10-17 18:43:10.113 I/Chronometer: initWeeklyView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:43:11.411 I/Chronometer: initWeeklyView завершен!
2020-10-17 18:43:11.411 I/Chronometer: initRankingView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:43:12.530 I/Chronometer: initRankingView завершен!
2020-10-17 18:43:12.530 I/Chronometer: initRankingMonthView инициирован!
2020-10-17 18:43:13.482 I/Chronometer: initRankingMonthView завершен!
```

Код из MainActivity:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_browse -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.browse)
                true
            }
            R.id.navigation_explore -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.explore)
                true
            }
            R.id.navigation_library -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.library)
                true
            }
            R.id.navigation_profile -> {
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
    navView.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_browse
```

Comment: Но в приведенном коде вообще нет вызова этих методов!

Comment: Тупанул. Я вызываю их из OnCreateView фрагмента.

Comment: Какого фрагмента?

Comment: как бы инициализацию view нужно производить в onViewCreated, а не в onCreateView

Comment: @danilshik, перенос инициализации в другое место не решает проблемы.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, Browse. R.id.navigation_browse